# How to Compare Date between 2 different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get LastAmount and CurrentAmount from a table which has latest Date between this two tables? For example, I want to get value from 2016 March, but the result I need is a value from the latest date.

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Comment: So for a given date (e.g. May 31, 2016) you want to find the last record created till then? Can it happen that there are two records with the same `CreatedDate`? What to do then?

Comment: till selected month in my report. I mean last record of the month I choose

Comment: Well okay, till "May 2016" is essentially the same as till "May 31, 2016". And you haven't answered what to do when both tables contain a record for May 31, 2016, 23:59:59, or if that is even possible. alex' solution would give you one of the two records arbitrarily chosen. If you want both, then add `with ties` to the top clause.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. now I can see the result I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
* 
FROM (
        (SELECT * FROM TABLE1)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT * FROM TABLE2)
     ) AS T WHERE monthCondition
ORDER BY T.CreatedData DESC
```